# Erro: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" ao inserir valor em tabela com trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, trigger

Após criar a *trigger*:

```
DELIMITER #

CREATE TRIGGER BACKUP_PRODUTO_INS
AFTER INSERT ON PRODUTO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BACKUP.BKP_PRODUTO VALUES(NULL, NEW.IDPRODUTO, NEW.NOME, NEW.VALOR, 'I');
END
#

DELIMITER ;
```

#### *DESC* da tabela `PRODUTO`:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| IDPRODUTO | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NOME      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VALOR     | float(10,2) | YES  |     | NULLL   |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

#### *DESC* da tabela `BKP_PRODUTO`:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| IDBKP     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| IDPRODUTO | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NOME      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VALOR     | float(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EVENTO    | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Ao executar o seguinte *statement*:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUTO VALUES(NULL, "LIVRO TESTE", 100.00);
```

O seguinte erro é gerado no MySQL 5.7:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Não consigo identificar o erro, já que os valores inseridos correspondem aos estipulados em ambas as tabelas. Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar o problema?

Comment: Jovem, você tem na tabela Produto o campo IDPRODUTO  que não aceita NULL, no entanto estás a fazer um Insert com NULL

Comment: Mas no mysql, ao inserir se dissermos que o campo é null ele reconhece e autoincrementa, mas quem sabe pode ser isso

Comment: Testei aqui seu insert e funcionou. Tem certeza de que são realmente esses campos?

Comment: acredito que seria uma boa prática adicionar os nomes das colunas no insert porque se no futuro você adicionar mais colunas, seu insert fica bagunçado.

Comment: @ClaudioLopes no MySQL é possível setar um valor NULL para um AUTO_INCREMENT, o valor da auto incrementação é gerado automaticamente pelo banco. Pode não ser uma boa prática, mas é possível e funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode setar o `null` para o campo `IDPRODUTO` pois ele não pode ser nulo, como sua estrutura mostra, e também já é `auto_increment`, então ele gera automaticamente a sequência pelo contador interno.

O correto é setar somente os campos que irá passar os valores:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (`NOME`,`VALOR`) VALUES ("LIVRO TESTE", 100.00);
```

As vezes seu banco não obriga o " ` ", então pode tirar:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (NOME,VALOR) VALUES ("LIVRO TESTE", 100.00);
```

Para adicionar vários de uma só vez:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (`NOME`,`VALOR`) VALUES ("LIVRO TESTE 1", 100.00), ("LIVRO TESTE 2", 200.00), ("LIVRO TESTE 3", 300.00);
```

Para a sua trigger, é só acertar seu INSERT trazendo as informações necessárias, basicamente:

```
INSERT INTO BACKUP.BKP_PRODUTO (`IDPRODUTO`,`NOME`,`VALOR`,`EVENTO`) VALUES (NEW.IDPRODUTO, NEW.NOME, NEW.VALOR, 'I');
```

Complementando:

Você pode sim passar somente os `VALUES` sem os campos, se for enviar todos os campos que contém na tabela, atendendo as características e ordem.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUTO VALUES (10, "LIVRO TESTE", 100.00);
```

> Uma boa opção para aprender, é usar o Mysql Workbench, pois toda
>   alteração, inserção, modificação, etc, ele mostra todo o código para
>   você.

[Veja mais](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Após seguir todas suas dicas, continuo com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Douglas, precisa ir por partes então. Tente fazer um insert manualmente sem a trigger. Até aí está dando certo ?

Comment: Resolvi o problema, eu tinha duas triggers para a mesma tabela PRODUTO, uma trigger mostrava que tal produto foi inserido ('I'), a outra trigger mostrava que tal produto foi deletado ('D'), acontece que eu tinha feito a trigger de produto deletado primeiro e por último a trigger de insert, mudando a ordem de criação das trigger, ou seja, colocando a trigger de insert primeiro e a de delete por último, funcionou sem problema! Não sei se isso realmente faz alguma diferença, mas foi assim que consegui resolver o problema, sabe me dizer se tem alguma relação a ordem de criação das triggers?

Comment: Não teria nenhum problema. A trigger (traduzindo: gatilho) são disparadas quando há uma ação na sua tabela. Então se ela se encaixa na condição, vai disparar. Mas além disso, você corrigiu seus inserts correto ? Porque não tem como deixar os `null` como você mostrou na pergunta.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que pensei, não vejo relação lógica na ordem de criação das triggers, e não! Não "corrigi" meus inserts, apontei o valor NULL dentro das trigger e funcionou! Concordo que fica confuso e pode não ser uma boa prática, mas funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problemas, e somente apos a correção da trigger de insert, mencionando as variaveis dentro que deu certo, e foi depois da trigger delete, e fiz vice e versa tbm, mas deu de boas.
Segue:

```
delimiter $

create trigger backup_produto
    after insert on PRODUTO
    for each ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO BACKUP.BKP_PRODUTO (`IDPRODUTO`,`NOME`,`VALOR`) 
    VALUES (NEW.IDPRODUTO, NEW.NOME, NEW.VALOR);


END
$

delimiter ;
```